# How to use "conclude" in a phrase?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Can "conclude" be used in the following way:

a) conclude by the fact that...
--> e.g. He is smart. This, one can conclude by the fact that he solved the tasks easily.

b)from x one can conclude that ...
--> e.g. From his behaviour one can conclude that he is an only child.

Comment: b) is better. We conclude **from** x that y is true. We also simply conclude **that** y is true. But we conclude **by** saying, "Thank you and goodnight!" So sentence a) should be "_This one can conclude **from** the fact that he solved the tasks easily_". [No comma after 'this'.] See [definitions **1** and **2**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/conclude) at Lexico.

Comment: Thank you! :) :)

Comment: a is OK, but is very literary. It's not something that you would use in everyday speech.

Answer (score 0):

b) is better. We conclude **from** x that y is true. We also simply conclude **that** y is true. But we conclude **by** saying, "Thank you and goodnight!"

So sentence a) should be:

> This one can conclude **from** the fact that he solved the tasks easily. [No comma after 'this'.]

See [definitions 1 and 2](https://www.lexico.com/definition/conclude) at Lexico. –
Old Brixtonian

Comment: Converting answer comment